# SendMail fails to send zipped folder

Tags: email

I have run into a problem sending mail from within Mathematica. I can send attachments of most file types: .jpg, .nb, .xls, etc. I have run into a problem trying to send a zipped folder. I have looked for an explanation both here and on Gmail help, but have not been able to determine the cause of the problem. Any insight would be appreciated. Shown below are an example of an operation that works and an operation that fails.

The following works fine:

```
SendMail[
"To" -> "gandalf@gmail.com",
"Subject" -> "Example of email sent from Mathematica",
"Body" -> 
"Hi.. I am testing something. There should be a picture attached.",
"Attachments" -> "picture.JPG",
"From" -> "frodo@gmail.com",
"Server" -> "smtp.gmail.com",
"UserName" -> "frodo@gmail.com",
"Password" -> Automatic,
"PortNumber" -> 587,
"EncryptionProtocol" -> "StartTLS"]

{"MessageID" -> "28093986415665034269.14.WolframLanguage.frodo@gmail.com"}
```

Whereas this fails:

```
SendMail[
"To" -> "gandalf@gmail.com",
"Subject" -> "Example of email sent from Mathematica",
"Body" -> 
"Hi.. I am testing something. There should be a zipped folder attached.",
"Attachments" -> "stuff.zip",
"From" -> "frodo@gmail.com",
"Server" -> "smtp.gmail.com",
"UserName" -> "frodo@gmail.com",
"Password" -> Automatic,
"PortNumber" -> 587,
"EncryptionProtocol" -> "StartTLS"]

SendMail::timeout: A network operation for SendMail timed out. Please try again later. >>

$ Failed
```

Comment: What is in stuff.zip?  gmail blocks zip files that contain zip files or executables.  See [Some file types are blocked](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590).

Comment: I had seen this. The zip file only contains a couple of PDFs.

Comment: @navillus5 so you have tried e-mailing other domains and it also fails?

Comment: @rhermans I just performed a test - I send emails through both gmail and my university's server. I sent emails to a number of different addresses as well. All worked when I sent a single pdf, all failed whe sending a zipped folder containing three .xlsx files. *("SendMail::timeout: A network operation for SendMail timed out. Please try again later. >>)*

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this Gmail limitation before... a workaround is to change the extension to something that is not blocked. Awesome security 'feature'.

For a compressed file like zip or 7z, simply change the file extension to .z and it should work. (.zipp might work too, but haven't personally used that)

#### To automate this...

The `RenameFile` documentation shows the basics of how to automate this:

Basically, use `CopyFile` to create a temp copy somewhere, rename this temp copy with `RenameFile`, as in `"myCopiedFile.z"`, then use your `SendMail` routine. If the output from `SendMail` is not `$Failed`---in V10 you can use `FailureQ` for this check---you can use `DeleteFile` to clean up the temp (renamed) copy.

#### Side note...

If you are on Windows, file extensions known to Windows are usually hidden by default.

If you wanted to rename extensions 'by hand' you must change Windows 'Folder Options' -> 'View' tab -> uncheck 'Hide extensions for known file types'. I usually make this change for all folders, but I think you can just change the option for a specific folder and its subfolder(s), if you want.